# Browsers needs a HTTP response, but server is not allowing multiple responses

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, redux

This is my handler that sends out a PUT request to my server:

```
    export function insertRandomQuestionsHandler(roomId, questions) {

    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(questionOverviewHandler(questions));
        let result = questions.reduce((r, e) => (r.push(...e), r), []);
        const url = . `http://localhost:3000/quizzer/room/${roomId}/selectedQuestions`;
        const response = fetch(url, {
            method: "PUT",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                questions: result,
                })
            });
        if (response.error) {
            throw new Error(`HTTP PUT request went wrong: got . 
   "${response.statusText}" for "${url}"`)
        }
        dispatch(insertRandomQuestions(result))
    }
}
```

On the server it goes through this request:

```
    quizzer.put('/room/:roomId/selectedQuestions', async function (req, res) {

    for (let i = 0; i < req.body.questions.length; i++) {
        await Room.findOneAndUpdate({roomId: req.params.roomId}, {
            "$push": {
                "questions": [{
                    "_id": req.body.questions[i]._id,
                    "question": req.body.questions[i].question,
                    "answer": req.body.questions[i].answer,
                    "category": req.body.questions[i].category,
                    "isShown": false,
                }]
            }
        },(err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).send(err);
            }
                return res.status(200).json(data);
            });
        }
   });
```

For some reason the browser needs a response else the request will be stuck at being pending and eventually return ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE:

[image: img1]

But when I return a response (data) as shown above (the http request is 200)

[image: img2]

Then my server crashes:

```
    Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent
```

So... I need that response to be sent, but it can't be sent twice.. 
Any ideas?

Comment: If you read it as psudeocode you're saying: foreach question findOneAndUpdate and send a response. You need to update all at once before sending a response or come up with another strategy. You can't send a response for each item in a for loop. You can have 1 response.

Comment: that does make sense.. I have to find a solution for that

Comment: One way - and there are many ways - would be to prepare all of the documents inside the forloop or better yet, using map. Then once you've prepared all the documents do something like a bulk upsert. Then return a response when that's done. However if you have many documents and preparing them is going to be a long operation you'll want to look at another strategy.